# Зафиксировать первое значение переменной Point location = this->Location;

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

```
System::Void ENTER_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
    {
        Point location = this->Location;
        this->Text = location.ToString();
        int static k = 0;
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::Enter)
        {
            if (k == 0) {
                this->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
                k=1;
            }
            else {
                this->Location = System::Drawing::Point(location);
                k=0;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Значение переменной при первом нажатии на Enter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При втором

Comment: Что должен делать этот код и что происходит не так?

Comment: Компонент должен перемещаться в нулевые координаты, а потом возвращаться  на исходное место, при нажатии на Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас код на четных шагах получает текущий `Location` и устанавливает его обратно, ничего не меняя:

```
Point location = this->Location;
//...
     this->Location = System::Drawing::Point(location);
```

Чтобы возвращаться к предыдущему положению, нужно его сохранить

Это может выглядеть так:

```
//инициализация 
static Point previousLocation = Point(0,0);
//сохраняем положение
Point location = this->Location;

//...
//установливаем на предыдущее место
    this->Location = previousLocation;

//запоминаем для следующего раза
previousLocation = location;
```